# Nginx Bad Gateway Flask + UWSGI

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm currently working on an app where my Front-end is a React app and the Back-end is a Flask app. I'm currently serving both applications via Nginx off a CentOS RHEL 7 server.

While my react app seems to be deployed, I can't seem to access my Flask API- it always results in a `502 Gateway Error` (Note: All my Flask routes are prefixed with `/api`)

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        server_name mywebsite.com;

        root /WebApp/client/build;

        index index.html;

        location / {
           try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;
            include cors_support;
            uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/WebApp/server/mywebsite.sock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the nginx error log? Try to move /api to before / locationl

Comment: Thanks- moving `/api` before `/` seemed to fix the problem!